# Handling 301 and checking if Final URL Exists

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, system.net, system.web

I'm using the following code to check if a URL is Valid.This works as intended for Most URLs but produces False Positive Results in cases of `HTTP 301` Responses.For example the URL http://www.amazon.com has 301 redirect in place.
When using this online tool http://www.urlitor.com it shows HTTP Status
(final destination) as 200.

I have set `request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;` in my code.But it does not seem to work as intended.Please advice.

```
try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                    return (response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: I tried your code and get 200 for amazon.com

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew Dont know why this happens ... The online service i used also reports 301

Comment: can you try to get more info from "tracert"?

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew Yes, I'm currently outside ... I will post it when I get back.Thanks

Comment: @VanPeer hmm...

Comment: because it's redirecting http to https!

Comment: @VanPeer In that case my program would report the link as invalid.How to fix this issue ?

Comment: @techno for redirects 301/302, write a different logic perhaps before the return

Comment: @VanPeer What kind of logic... How to find the redirect URL and check again if it's valid ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163629/discussion-between-van-peer-and-techno).